# Analysis of Sonata form

Tags: theory, piano, harmony, musical-forms, sonata

I’m about to take my level 10 Harmony exam and I’m still kind of unsure about Sonata Form. Could someone give a (brief?) explanation of it? The textbook that I use does have a good explanation, but I’d love to hear another explanation in different words I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question proposed as a duplicate should give the answer you're looking for, but here's some brief detail to get you started.

```
Part 1: Exposition  
1.1 First theme / first key area  
1.2 Transition  
1.3 Second theme / second key area
1.4 Transition / Ending

Part 2: Development
2.1 Development of thematic or other material
2.2 Retransition

Part 3: Recapitulation
3.1 First theme / first key area
3.2 Transition
3.3 Second theme / first key area
3.4 Transition / Ending / Coda
```